# How to set popover size in Monotouch.Dialog?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have the following setup:

- my controller inherits `UINavigationController`.
- It holds a member of `DialogViewController`
- My controller's `ContentSizeForViewInPopover` is set to 400|400
- The DialogViewController's `ContentSizeForViewInPopover` is also set to 400|400

One of the elements in the dialog view controller discloses a long list of sub elements. If this list is longer than the 400 units I defined, the popover controller's height will be increased if this list is pushed on the navigation controller. This is fine, however if I go back to the previous menu, the size won't be resized to the 400 units I defined.

Is there a way to tell `DialogViewController` to not change the size?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show code for your specific usage of MonoTouch.Dialog? You may be seeing this behavior because every time the TopViewController changes...UIPopoverController will attempt to auto-negotiate it's own ContentSize.

You should set the ContentSizeForViewInPopover for each UIViewController being presented by overriding the WillShowViewController method and setting the SizeF there.

```
public class NavDelegate : UINavigationControllerDelegate 
{
    public NavDelegate()
        : base() 
    {
    }

    public override void WillShowViewController(UINavigationController navigationController, UIViewController viewController, bool animated)
    {
        base.WillShowViewController(navigationController, viewController, animated);

        viewController.ContentSizeForViewInPopover = new SizeF(.., ..);
    }
}
```